# Cannot connect TcpClient to TcpListener Visual Basic .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, sockets, tcp, tcpclient

I' trying hard to create TCP server and client. I got a lot of tutorials like [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/11178/A-Peer-To-Peer-LAN-Chat-Application-in-Visual-Basic-Net-using-TcpClient-and-TcpListener.html) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=RU-RU&k=k(System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true). But still can't succeed!

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

Private Server As TcpListener = Nothing
Private ServerThread As Thread = Nothing
Private WithEvents Tray As New NotifyIcon
Private myClient As TcpClient = Nothing
Dim localAddr As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.115")


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Server = New TcpListener(localAddr, 40000)
    ServerThread = New Thread(AddressOf ConnectionListener)
    ServerThread.IsBackground = True
    ServerThread.Start()
    TextBox1.Text = "Server is ready!"

' function I use to get all the TCP clients I can see in local web. 
' You can find it by the first link (see at the top of the post)
    lbComputers.DataSource = GetNetworkComputers() 

End Sub

Private Sub ConnectionListener()
    Try
        Server.Start()
        While True
            myClient = Server.AcceptTcpClient
            'myClient.Connect("MSK4", 40000) 'tried this: didn't work
            Dim T As New Thread(AddressOf SomeClientActions)
            T.Start(myClient)
            TextBox2.Text = "Client connected" ' It's always empty :(

            End While



            myClient.Close()
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to Accept Connections", "Server Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try
    Application.ExitThread()

End Sub

Private Sub SomeClientActions(ByVal client As Object)
    ' ... do something with "client" in here ...
    Invoke(Sub() TextBox2.Text = "This text is never appears :(")
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    'myClient.Close() 'error is here
    Server.Stop()
End Sub

End Class
```

And I have two TextBoxes (TextBox1 and TextBox2). I get `Server is ready!` in the first one but never get anything in the second! So I suppose I can't connect to my server! Code after this row:

```
myClient = Server.AcceptTcpClient
```

Is never executes.
I tried to use just

```
myClient.Connect("MSK4", 40000)
```

As my computer name is MSK4 but then I get my exception and MessageBox.
**How to realize the connect? What I do wrong?**

Comment: Care to share the error message?

Comment: There is no error message, but as You can see I try to send text to TextBox2 if client was successfully connected, but its always empty!

Comment: Try connecting to "127.0.0.115" instead of MSK4 for testing purpose

Comment: By the way, this is the server side of the connection. I am presuming that you have coded the client which actually connects to this server.

Comment: @athar13 I tried "127.0.0.115" and get the same - always messageBox from Exception - so I can't connect to server.
Hmm is this only server side? Look at `ConnectionListener()` function - I try to create client here. And try to connect here. Maybe here is some mistake?

Comment: Not really. That function is called everytime the ServerThread is run. This is the server saying, I am ready to accept clients and waits for a client to connect. Only when a client makes a request to the server, does the server actually proceed to the next line. Moreover, this variable myClient has to be local to the function and not global. This is a temporary variable to read or rather receive what the actual client is sending.

Comment: In the second link in your question, the client is a link at the bottom of the article. Just after the server code.

Comment: You said you weren't getting an error but you are getting a message box in the catch block so there is an exception ocurring.  Try adding the exception message and stack trace from the exception to your message box and post that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the server listen to `127.0.0.115` means it will only accept connections ***from that specific IP***. To listen for connections from any IP you need to specify `0.0.0.0` or [**`IPAddress.Any`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any(v=vs.110).aspx).

As for making connections you must use IP-addresses only, computer names won't work.

Comment: Wow! It's not really the problem, but I didn't know that so It is problem too! I think now I need to improve my code!
Really useful!